# Post thumbnail won't resize to fit

Tags: post-thumbnails

Below is the code i used to set my thumbnail sizes. The Only problem I'm having is that my thumbnails won't resize to fit the size below or the `<div>`

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 760, 330, true ); // Normal post thumbnails
```

Some images may be small but shouldn't they stretch themselves to proportion to fit the thumbnail size specified in the code above. Can any one tell me hop i can accomplish this. I have also tried adding a thumbnail size and calling it and it still didn't work.

I have also used the 'Thumbnail Regenerator' plugin to regenerate size, but they still don't fit. Why is this.

Here is an example below, notice that the second thumbnail doesn't fit.

[image]

Comment: "Some images may be small but shouldn't they stretch themselves to proportion to fit the thumbnail size specified in the code above." ... if they are smaller then the content, then they won't get upscaled (and if, then only with a decent loss of quality).

Answer (score 0):

change true to false in set_post_thumbnail_size( 760, 330, true )

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 760, 330, false );
```

This will make it not crop automatically.

Comment: That didn't help it only only made the images smaller

Comment: The 3rd value is _crop_.